# _CGAffineTransformScale error on xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode3.2

Can anyone help me to solved this xcode error?

```
error :   "_CGAffineTransformScale", referenced from:
```

Is Xcode missing any library for `CGAffineTransformScale` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the CoreGraphics framework is added to the project.